# Changing the value of a react input component with JS doesn't fire the inputs onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-testing-library

I have a range input that has a few things happening `onChange`.  This works as I'd expect with manual click/drag usage.  However, when I try to change the value with JavaScript, my `onChange` event doesn't seem to fire.

**Here is my code:**

```
const App = () => {
  const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState(0);

  const setRangeValue = () => {
    const range = document.querySelector("input");

    range.value = 50;
    range.dispatchEvent(new Event("change", { bubbles: true }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Current Value: {currentValue}</h1>

      <input
        type="range"
        min={0}
        max={100}
        step={10}
        onChange={e => {
          console.log("Change!");
          setCurrentValue(+e.target.value);
        }}
        defaultValue={0}
      />

      <button onClick={setRangeValue}>Set current value to 50</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**And here it is (not) working in CodeSandbox:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-resonance-rps1n

**NOTE:**

Just to clarify.  My actual issue comes from testing my component with jest/react testing library.  The button demo is just a nice way to visualize the problem without getting into the weeds of having to duplicate all of my test stuff too.

```
    const getMessage = (value, message) => {
        const slider = getByRole('slider');
        fireEvent.change(slider, { target: { value } });
        slider.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));
        return getByText(message).innerHTML;
    };
```

When the fireEvent changes the value, it doesn't run the `onChange` events attached to the input.  Which means that `getByText(message).innerHTML` is incorrect, as that will only update when a set hook gets called `onChange`.  (All of this works when manually clicking/dragging the input slider, I just can't "test" it)

Any help would be great!

Comment: Your input value should be controlled by state and then on button click should utilize setCurrentValue. What you doing in setRangeValue is not the react way.suggest you read some of React docs on forms.

Comment: @gaditzkhori How would you suggest controlling the state in a test?  To me, that just seems like forcing a specific outcome that would nullify the test I'm trying to run?

Comment: this is how the ui  should behave as in the React way https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-wildflower-okzmr.
in your test if you fire a click event on the button the input value expected to change

Comment: FYI, did you see the above comment?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that React has a virtual DOM which doesn't connect directly to the DOM. Note how the events from React are SyntheticEvents. They are not the actual event from the DOM.
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1152

If this is for a unit test, create a separate component for the slider and text and make sure they perform as expected separate from each other with props.

For a more in-depth article on how to specifically test a range slider, checkout https://blog.bitsrc.io/build-and-test-sliders-with-react-hooks-38aaa9422772

Best of luck to ya!